# How to implement signin via google apps account in javascript or jquery?

Tags: authentication, google-apps

How to implement signin via **Google Apps** account in javascript or jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google API Javascript Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) with [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent). It works por Google Apps accounts as well as consumer accounts, you can validate the domain after the user signs in. Another option is to use [Google+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) which offer other additional benefits.